# Underscore template doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Since I'm using underscore templates with ruby I want to change default `<% %>` tags which both ruby and underscore template use, so I setup the underscore to use other tags like this:

```
<script>

    _.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\[\=(.+?)\]/g,
      evaluate: /\[(.+?)\]/g
    };

</script>
```

So my template isn't that much complicated :

```
<script type="text/html" id='table_list_rows_template'>
    [
    _.each(items,function(obj,key){

    var median = obj.md.toFixed(4)
  ]
  <tr>
    <td>[= key + 1]</td>
    <td>[= obj.name]</td>
    <td>[= median]</td>
  </tr>

  [ }); ]
```

So when I try to render html from template like this (`tuples` is list of objects and my table has id `table_list`) :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var template = $("#table_list_rows_template").html();
        $("#table_list tbody").html(_.template(template,{items:tuples}));
    });

    </script>
      </script>
```

So I get the following error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

And it should be on this line :

```
$("#table_list tbody").html(_.template(template,{items:tuples}));
```

But I can't spot the error. What is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE :**

I've tried to change from [] to `<? ?>` like php style because first one reminds of javascript array so I figured that might cause problems. See below :

```
_.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /<\?\=(.+?)\?>/g,
      evaluate: /<\?(.+?)\?>/g
    };

<script type="text/html" id='table_list_rows_template'>

    <? 
            _.each(items,function(obj,key, list){
    ?>

  <tr id='response_[= obj.id]'>
    <td></td>
    <td><?= obj.name ?></td>
  </tr>

  <? }); ?>

  </script>
```

Made no difference same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your template settings from "."  to "[\s\S]":

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\[\=([\s\S]+?)\]/g,
  evaluate: /\[([\s\S]+?)\]/g
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBTMw/4/ with the \s\S 
http://jsfiddle.net/zBTMw/5/ with the . (has the error)

The latest version of underscore.js uses the [\s\S] construct, which is where I got the idea.